# JavaMelody with multiple web apps

Tags: tomcat, java-melody

I would like to use JavaMelody to monitor multiple Java web apps (app1, app2, app3) individually.
My server is Tomcat9.

Is it simply copy the files javamelody.jar and jrobin-1.5.9.jar to the WEB-INF/lib directory of the each war (app1, app2, app3) of the webapp to monitor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is. The javamelody jar file and the jrobin-1.5.9.jar file should be copied in each WEB-INF/lib.

Doc: https://github.com/javamelody/javamelody/wiki/UserGuide#javamelody-setup

Comment: can't I enable javamelody for entire tomcat, not for each webapp

Comment: @Chandika no, you can't. The goal of javamelody is to monitor metrics and requests in each webapp individually. And it is needed to copy javamelody and jrobin jar files in each WEB-INF/lib